# Print html/css layout after js window.open

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with printing output in opened window via javascript. I create new document via `window.open` with included CDN links to bootstrap files. In opened window everything looks ok but if i use print (XPS document writer) some styles are here (`.btn-group`) but layout or inline styles are not.

Q: How i can print what i see in new window?

In link on CDN i have `media='all'` (but tried `media='print'` too).

Working example:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5855/)

```
$('#openNewWindow').click(function(e){
    var printWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1100, height=500');

    printWindow.document.open();
    printWindow.document.write("<!doctype html><head><title>title</title>");

    var cdn = `
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">        
    `;

    printWindow.document.write(cdn);        
    printWindow.document.write("</head><body>");

    content = `
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: red">.col-md-8</div>
              <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: blue">.col-md-4</div>
            </div>            
        </div>

    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    `;

    printWindow.document.write(content);        
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    printWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    printWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    setTimeout(function () {
        printWindow.print();
    },1000)

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure why, but Bootstrap 3 print work with XS size (col-xs-*), so you can rewrite your popup for print to XS or find css fix for that

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have body of default auto width dimension, and in the body only floating/unrestriced divs, they will go layouted for print square in implicit browser ways.

You should define either fixed body width and in it the floated/positioned  unrestricted divs, (or define divs widths instead etc.)

You can define those additional styles you do not wish to affect the main document (such as fixed body width) in a print dedicated style document, such  as this:

```
<link href="printspecific.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And there experiment until you detect missing appropriate styling, so paper ready document will behave as you wish. I'm guessing that the defined width of body element would be enough to have layout look correct.